# R: Row wise sum of cells in each column

Tags: r, sum

I have created a table where I have entered some values in the first three columns. I now want to compute the sum of all the cells in each row separately in a fourth column.
eg:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4
1  2  3  6 
4  5  6  15
```

Here, there are some values in the first three columns and the fourth column has the sum of the first three cells in each row. Can anyone suggest a method?

Comment: Another option would be `addmargins(as.matrix(df1), 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```
T <- cbind(T,rowSums(T))
```

if T is the table.

Comment: Thanks mate! It worked.

Comment: It is better to update `T` instead of copying the whole data. `T["res"] <- rowSums(T)`, should be a better option IMO

Answer (score 1):

You could try `apply()` with the function `sum`:

```
df$v5 <- apply(df,1,sum)
> df
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  1  2  3  6 12
#2  4  5  6 15 30
```

Here the value of the second parameter in `apply()`, 1, indicates that the sum should be performed for each row of the dataframe.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="v1 v2 v3 v4
                        1  2  3  6 
                        4  5  6  15", header=T)
```